# How to implement hook-validation in sails.js?

Tags: sails.js

I am trying to apply hook validation for my App. I searched through google but couldn't find proper way to do that please help.

[Sails-hook-validation](https://github.com/lykmapipo/sails-hook-validation)

My Model:

```
module.exports = {
attributes: {
    username: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }
    confirmPassword:{
           required: true,
           unique: true
    }
},
//model validation messages definitions
validationMessages: { 
    password: {
        required: 'password is required',

    },
    username: {
        required: 'Username is required'
         unique: 'username is already taken'
    }
 }
};
```

If I click Submit button with empty fields."validationMessages" from model should popup in my view page.I wonder how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The README file of the repository is expressive. You have to give more details about your problem to obtain an answer. Code, logs ...

Comment: sorry for late reply..I need to show error message from model in my View when adding new user.